Alembic doesn't initialize with asyncio
I can't run: *alembic revision --autogenerate -m "initial revision
cause face with :
File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/vpnbot_via_dialog/migration/env.py", line 7, in <module>
  from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncAttrs, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine

ImportError: cannot import name 'AsyncAttrs' from 'sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/__init__.py

Alembic 1.13.3
sqlalchemy 2.0.35
python 3.12

env.py code :
import asyncio
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import pool
from sqlalchemy.engine import Connection
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncAttrs, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine


from alembic import context
from bot.db.database import Base, DATABASE_URL
from bot.db.models import Users, Configs, Servers

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url",DATABASE_URL)
# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = Base.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def do_run_migrations(connection: Connection) -> None:
    context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata)

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


async def run_async_migrations() -> None:
    """In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    connectable = async_engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    async with connectable.connect() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(do_run_migrations)

    await connectable.dispose()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode."""

    asyncio.run(run_async_migrations())


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()

database.py code :
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio

from sqlalchemy import ARRAY, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array
from sqlalchemy.orm import  declarative_base, Mapped, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncAttrs, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.testing.schema import mapped_column

from bot.config.config import settings


DATABASE_URL = settings.get_db_url()

engine = create_async_engine(url=DATABASE_URL)
async_session_maker = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)

# Base class for models
class Base(AsyncAttrs, declarative_base()):
    __abstract__ = True

Try only to reinstall libs,python env (supose problem in os ). Google couldn't help.
This command (**) must create a conversion file (Python script) that contains changes to the database schemas. If changes were found in the current database with SQLAlchemy models, they will be listed in the schemas in this file. Initial revision is the first revision scheme.
But it throw error.

The answer is: Alembic: alembic revision says Import Error After that i also add "." to the         prefix="sqlalchemy" in env.py def run_async_migrations().
